# Routed Page Links for Pagination Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

I am using Troy Goode's [PagedList](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) plugin on my Asp.Net MVC 5 application.

I created a route for my controller accepting a "page" parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewsPaged",
    url: "News/Page-{page}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Haberler", action = "Liste", page = 1 }
);
```

And this is how I'am creating the links:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Liste", new { page }))
```

I can manually type the url like: "http://domain.com/news/page-4"

It works. But I couldn't find a way to modify the page links in order to apply these routed urls on them. The page link buttons at the bottom show the urls with a query string parameter like `/news&page=4`

How can that be achieved?

Comment: How are you creating those links?

Comment: My apoligies, I forgot to add that. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use:

`@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.RouteUrl("NewsPaged", new { page }))`

Comment: That my friend, just thought me a new thing :) Didn't know that routes could be called by name. Thank you!